# Filtering selected columns based on column aggregate

Tags: python-polars

I wish to select only columns with fewer than 3 unique values. I can generate a boolean mask via `pl.all().n_unique() < 3`, but I don't know if I can use that mask via the polars API for this.

Currently, I am solving it via python. Is there a more idiomatic way?

```py
import polars as pl, pandas as pd
df = pl.DataFrame({"col1":[1,1,2], "col2":[1,2,3], "col3":[3,3,3]})
# target is:
# df_few_unique = pl.DataFrame({"col1":[1,1,2], "col3":[3,3,3]})

# my attempt:
mask = df.select(pl.all().n_unique() < 3).to_numpy()[0]
cols = [col for col, m in zip(df.columns, mask) if m]
df_few_unique = df.select(cols)
df_few_unique
```

Equivalent in pandas:

```py
df_pandas = df.to_pandas()
mask = (df_pandas.nunique() < 3)
df_pandas.loc[:, mask]
```

Comment: We had that functionality but we cleaned a lot lately when we purged deprecated code. I think your use case is a valid one, so we reintroduced it: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/4535

Will be available in next release.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: after some thinking, I discovered an even easier way to do this, one that doesn't rely on boolean masking at all.

```py
pl.select(
    [s for s in df
     if s.n_unique() < 3]
)
```

```
shape: (3, 2)
┌──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col3 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ 1    ┆ 3    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1    ┆ 3    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2    ┆ 3    │
└──────┴──────┘
```

##### Previous answer

One easy way is to use the `compress` function from Python's `itertools`.

```py
from itertools import compress
df.select(compress(df.columns, df.select(pl.all().n_unique() < 3).row(0)))
```

```
>>> df.select(compress(df.columns, df.select(pl.all().n_unique() < 3).row(0)))
shape: (3, 2)
┌──────┬──────┐
│ col1 ┆ col3 │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ 1    ┆ 3    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1    ┆ 3    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2    ┆ 3    │
└──────┴──────┘
```

`compress` allows us to apply a boolean mask to a list, which in this case is a list of column names.

```py
list(compress(df.columns, df.select(pl.all().n_unique() < 3).row(0)))
```

```
>>> list(compress(df.columns, df.select(pl.all().n_unique() < 3).row(0)))
['col1', 'col3']
```

Comment: I've updated the answer with a far more elegant solution.

Comment: That was indeed super elegant! That also taught me that the dataframe is iterable, which I hadn't realised!