# Selecting columns based on a condition in Polars

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I want to select columns in a Polars DataFrame based on a condition. In my case, I want to select all string columns that have less than 100 unique values. Naively I tried:

```
df.select((pl.col(pl.Utf8)) & (pl.all().n_unique() < 100))
```

which gave me an error, which is probably due to the second part of the expression.

```
df.select(pl.all().n_unique() < 100)
```

This doesn't select columns but instead returns a single row DataFrame of bool values. I'm new to polars and still can't quite wrap my head around the expression API, I guess. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Would this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73449117/20557510

Answer (score 6):

It's helpful if you include an example to save others from having to create one.

```
df = pl.DataFrame({
   "col1": ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
   "col2": ["A", "A", "C", "A"],
   "col3": ["A", "B", "A", "B"],
   "col4": [1, 2, 3, 4],
})
```

You are selecting the string columns with `pl.col(pl.Utf8)`

```
>>> df.select(pl.col(pl.Utf8))
shape: (4, 3)
┌──────┬──────┬──────┐
│ col1 | col2 | col3 │
│ ---  | ---  | ---  │
│ str  | str  | str  │
╞══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ A    | A    | A    │
│ B    | A    | B    │
│ C    | C    | A    │
│ D    | A    | B    │
└──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

You can chain `.n_unique()` to the `pl.col()` to run it just on those columns.

```
>>> df.select(pl.col(pl.Utf8).n_unique() < 3)
shape: (1, 3)
┌───────┬──────┬──────┐
│ col1  | col2 | col3 │
│ ---   | ---  | ---  │
│ bool  | bool | bool │
╞═══════╪══════╪══════╡
│ false | true | true │
└───────┴──────┴──────┘
```

You can loop over this result and extract the `.name` for each `true` column.

There is no `.is_true()` but `.all()` is equivalent.

```
>>> [ col.name for col in df.select(pl.col(pl.Utf8).n_unique() < 3) if col.all() ]
['col2', 'col3']
```

You can then select just those columns:

```
df.select(
   col.name for col in 
   df.select(pl.col(pl.Utf8).n_unique() < 3) 
   if col.all()
)
```

```
shape: (4, 2)
┌──────┬──────┐
│ col2 | col3 │
│ ---  | ---  │
│ str  | str  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ A    | A    │
│ A    | B    │
│ C    | A    │
│ A    | B    │
└──────┴──────┘
```

Comment: Thanks! would you agree that this is a little "un-polars-like" to choose this list comprehension syntax? i can see the benefits of the expressions API in polars but in this case the pandas way is just so much cleaner: `df.loc[:, df.dtypes.eq("object") & df.nunique().lt(100)]`

Comment: I think the closest to that type of syntax is `df[:, df.select(pl.col(pl.Utf8).n_unique().lt(100)).melt().filter(pl.col("value"))["variable"]]`

Comment: Perhaps `.drop()` could be made to accept expressions so one could write: `df.select(pl.col(pl.Utf8)).drop(pl.all().n_unique().gt(99))`

Comment: the first one works nicely. the second one sadly not due to the same reasons my snippet doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the name of the columns by doing a `melt` followed by a `groupby`, but I'm not too sure how to turn this into an expression

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "val1": ["a", "b", "c"],
        "val2": ["d", "d", "d"],
    }
)
columns = (
    df.select(pl.col(pl.Utf8))
    .melt()
    .groupby("variable")
    .agg(pl.col("value").n_unique())
    .filter(pl.col("value") >= 3)
    .get_column("variable")
    .to_list()
)
df.select(columns)
```